# Missing information from root element when generating XML file

Tags: xml, vbscript

This script should generate a new XML file and so far it works, but I'm stuck at the first line (`SimBase.Document`…).

This is the script:

```vb
Dim objShell, appdata
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
appdata = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")  

Set objRoot = xmlDoc.createElement("SimBase.Document")
xmlDoc.appendChild objRoot

Set objRecord = xmlDoc.createElement("Launch.Addon")
objRoot.appendChild objRecord 

Set objName = xmlDoc.createElement("Descr")
objName.Text = "Launch"
objRecord.appendChild objName

Set objName = xmlDoc.createElement("Filename")
objName.Text = "exe.xml"
objRecord.appendChild objName 

Set objName = xmlDoc.createElement("Disabled")
objName.Text = "False"
objRecord.appendChild objName

Set objName = xmlDoc.createElement("Launch.ManualLoad")
objName.Text = "False"
objRecord.appendChild objName

Set objIntro = xmlDoc.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0'")
xmlDoc.insertBefore objIntro,xmlDoc.childNodes(0)

xmlDoc.Save(appdata & "\Microsoft\FSX\exe.xml")
```

The outcome of my script at the first line is:

```xml
<SimBase.Document>
```

but it should be:

```xml
<SimBase.Document version="1,0" Type="Launch">
```

Answer (score 1):

Add lines

```
objRoot.setAttribute "version", "1,0"
objRoot.setAttribute "Type", "Launch"
```

Comment: hi ...where to add those lines?

Comment: After the `Set objRoot = xmlDoc.createElement("SimBase.Document")` which creates the element.

Comment: if I do this following error message comes up:                                   "Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub"

Comment: @aletri, sorry, `setAttribute` is certainly the method you need to call to set an attribute value on an element node, I guess I got the VBScript syntax wrong, see the edit.